# Combine dataframes from nested list in R

Tags: r, list

I have a named list of data which contains named data frames.

```
mlst = list(test = list(df = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 21:30), list(c(1:2))),
            test2 = list(df = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 21:30), list(c(1:2))))
mlst$test$df
mlst$test2$df
```

The function `do.call(rbind,mlst)` do not work as this is not picking up *only* the data frames. How could I bind the rows of only the dataframes without a for loop?

Comment: try `Reduce(rbind, Filter(is.data.frame, unlist(mlst, FALSE)))`

Comment: or even `do.call(rbind, Filter(is.data.frame, unlist(mlst, FALSE)))`

Comment: `Reduce(\(x,y)rbind(x,if(is.data.frame(y))y), unlist(mlst, FALSE))`

Comment: Avoiding loops means avoiding `apply`? If not, another solution: `do.call(rbind, find_df(mlst))`, where `find_df()` is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/70513095/20002111

Comment: It _used to be the case_ that `*apply` functions were (at times significantly) faster than many `for` loops, but that was fixed many versions ago. The decision to lean towards using `*apply` now should be made entirely based on the structure of the data and the desired structure of the result. The decision should not be made based on the presumption of "performance" or "cool R thing to do" :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the name of the data frame in each list is called "df" then you can extract those elements and row bind them like so:

```r
library(purrr)

map(mlst, "df") |>
  list_rbind()
```

In base R you can do something similar:

```r
lapply(mlst, `[[`, "df") |>
  do.call(rbind, args = _)
```